# What does 彼のままだった mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

In the following phrase:「時{とき}が過{す}ぎても彼{かれ}のままだった。」what does the「彼{かれ}のままだった」part mean?

My guess is that I can translate this phrase into something like "He's the same" or "he didn't change", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting how much the meaning changes if it's ママ instead of まま

Answer (score 2):

Nice guesses!

> 時{とき}が過{す}ぎても彼{かれ}のままだった。

could also be translated into something like this:

> "Even with the passing of time, *he was still the same as ever.*"